# Lua remove folders in file path from request uri

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have URL's like this:

```
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/96_6.txt
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/96_7.txt?blah=1
```

So far I am doing the following to obtain the file on the end of my URL:

```
local request_uri = "/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/96_645.txt?lol=1"
local name = request_uri:match( "([^/]+)$" )
local filename = string.gsub(name, "?.*", "")


print(name)
print(filename)
```

What outputs:

```
96_645.txt?lol=1
96_645.txt
```

What I want to do is to remove `path2` and `path3` from my URL. The issue is they are dynamic folder paths and can contain characters.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```lua
function fix_url(p)
  p, _ = string.gsub(p, '^/([^/]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)', '/%1/%2')
  return p
end
```

Here are some tests:

```lua
p = fix_url('/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/96_6.txt') 
assert(p == '/path1/path4/path5/96_6.txt')
p = fix_url('/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/96_7.txt?blah=1') 
assert(p == '/path1/path4/path5/96_7.txt?blah=1')
p = fix_url('/path1/foo.txt') 
assert(p == '/path1/foo.txt')
```

Comment: I modifed your regex to this. p, _ = string.gsub(p, '^/([^/]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)', '/%1/%2/%3') I am trying to keep path4 folder /path1/path4/96_645.txt?lol=1" and delete path5 folder but i am doing something wrong...